# JQuery if td value < nothing change color of table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a snipit of jquery that almost does what want, I want the row to change color not just the cell with the value.. can anyone help please been trying for hours

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.nr2').filter(function(){
return $.trim($(this).text()) > '0'
}).css('background-color', '#24AD36');

});
```

[fork on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Razor303/3fvzv86q/)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just chain the `parent()` method after the `filter()` to get the row

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nr2').filter(function () {
        return +($.trim($(this).text())) > 0
    }).parent().css('background-color', '#24AD36');

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dpyu0mhq/1/

---

As a side note, I suggest to set a class instead of a css property , just to keep off style from javascript and make the code mantainance easier, e.g.

Javascript

```
.parent().addClass('highlight');
```

CSS

```
.highlight {
  background-color: #24AD36
}
```

Comment: + for suggesting using class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()` to find the nearest `tr` element. I would also suggest you convert the `td` value to an integer to compare against `0`. Using greater than against strings can lead to some *interesting* results.

```
$('.nr2').filter(function () {
    return parseInt($.trim($(this).text()), 10) > 0
}).closest('tr').css('background-color', '#24AD36');
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bw7p5uxx/)